# counting instances of int in a string

Tags: java

Trying to count how many integers are within a string

```
System.out.println("Enter numbers, eg 1 2 3: ");
a = scan.nextLine();
b = count(a).length;
```

This does not work. Is there a simple method to do this?

Comment: How many integers are in "A three digit number: 123"  One? Three? Six?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d++").matcher(input);
    int n = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        n++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the characters and check if they're 0 <= char <= 9.

Answer (score 0):

try, the below code assumes only integers will be given as input separated by space

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers, eg 1 2 3: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine().trim();      
        String[] intArr = input.split(" "); 
        System.out.println("Length ::" +intArr.length);     
        scan.close();
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do following way

```
public class finalTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String x="abc0123456789";
char x1[]=x.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<x1.length;i++)
{
    //System.out.println(x1[i]);
    int x2=x1[i];
    System.out.println(x2);
}
    }

}
```

output

```
97
98
99
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
```

As you can see alphabets of small letter starts from 97 and integer values start from 48 and similarly capital letters start from  65.So now you can differentiate which are alphabets and which are integers